# addLinks to open activity or use span with grammar

Tags: android, android-studio, android-intent

I'm trying to make a hashtag system.
So I tried:

```
holder.textViewPublisher.setText(post.getPublisher());
Pattern tagMatcher = Pattern.compile("[#]+[A-Za-z0-9-_]+\\b");
String url = "https://www..com";
Linkify.addLinks(holder.textViewPublisher, tagMatcher, url);
```

This works but only to open an url. I want to open an activity sending the hashtag value to this.

How can I open an activity instead of a link?
Do I need to use span? any examples?

Comment: Do you want to open Activity of **your** app or **another** app?

Comment: @DEADMC another activity in my app (the same app).

Answer (score 1):

You can use [deeplinks](https://developer.android.com/training/app-indexing/deep-linking.html) with params.

So you will use same links which will look like

```
myapp://myhost?activity=activity_name
```

Then you just catch parameter activity as `String` for example and run activity you need.